# Does the CW post limit include deleted posts?

Tags: support, community-wiki, deleted-answers

It takes 30 answers to push a question automatically into Community Wiki. Does this include or exclude deleted answers?

Comment: Well, we could probably test that here...

Comment: OK, I added and deleted 5. Someone else can have a turn before some kind of spammer detection software sends a hit squad to my house.

Comment: @jon: First the squad, then I take over.

Comment: I would be shocked if it didn't exclude deleted answers, but okay, let's give it a shot.

Comment: Let's all provide an answer so that the answer randomizer makes a story out of them. So everyone add a sentence to make a story that makes sense no matter what order the sentences are read in. And then none of us are permitted to up or downvote any of the answers so that they're forever randomized. Who's with me?

Comment: Being blind to deleted answers while they are being written, I *greatly* look forward to seeing what kind of chaos comes from the combined answers.

Comment: OK - 31. We made it.

Comment: No community wiki yet!?

Comment: Well, we don't actually know what the threshold is on meta...It's 30 on SO, but not necessarily here.

Comment: ... how many of us (the "participants") can actually see the deleted posts? (and as such, the "story")

Comment: So, now the question becomes this... If all the deleted answers are now undeleted, will the question and answers auto-wiki upon the reappearance of the 30th answer?

Comment: @gnovice I actually think it probably won't trigger auto-wiki, much like [merging questions does not trigger it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A30+wiki%3A0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. 30 deleted answers will not force CW. (At least not on MSO).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the value isn't going to be *higher* than 30. [This search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A25+wiki%3A0) turns up nothing greater than 28 answers, so it's more reasonable that 30 remains the turning point.

Comment: @Grace, we could add 2 more answers to one of those posts to find out.

Comment: @Justin: [Your turn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume)

Comment: @Lady...everything went CW.   I feel kinda bad now...

Comment: @Justin: Good boy :)