# Why is the conversion to Community Wiki not in the edit history for this question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-wiki, revisions-list

Why does the CW conversion for this question not appear in the edit history?:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/12807/revisions

It was originally a non-CW question ([my answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true/12812#12812) to the question rep-capped me today).

Comment: Previously observed [here on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67607/141911) in the comments, although the post was later "un-wikied".

Comment: @Aarobot: You think the question was hacked?  Wouldn't it still leave an audit trail?

Comment: No, I doubt it was hacked; I was referring to my comment in there, where I pointed out that the CW was not showing up in the revision history even though the question was CW.  (Normally you'll see that message even when the question is started as CW.)  I think something funky happened on the back-end when they "fixed" the CW stuff last week.

Comment: There are 35 answers, which is over the non-CW limit.

Comment: @KennyTM: The automatic conversion to CW should still appear in the edit history.

Answer (score 2):

The question generates more than 30 answers (15 on Super User). In this case, the question and all answers will enter community mode, as will any future answers.

This rule you can find in the [FAQ about community wiki.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

In a rep recalc, all reputation earned before the wikification will be preserved. What has been awarded afterwards does not count though.

it seems as if this kind of conversion does not trigger an entry in the revision history.

Comment: Here's a [much older example of a question converted by the answer quantity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume). It looks like it's been doing this silently without updating the revision history for a while.

Comment: @Grace: That question was migrated from SO to SU while it was still non-CW, and is apparently above the CW conversion threshold for SU. So it might be an edge case.

Comment: @Robert You can't see it since he deleted his post, but it was converted to CW by jjnguy as part of the testing [over here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59612/does-the-cw-post-limit-include-deleted-posts/59650#59650). It turned Community Wiki on August 24th, 21:19:26 SO time. And... where is SU coming into all of this?

Comment: @Robert If you want, here are [three](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/163229/revisions) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12830/revisions) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/101055/revisions) where the question became CW because of getting answers more than the limit and the revision history does not record it. All 3 turned CW as a result of the botching of testing [in this comment exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53722/should-non-cw-answers-to-cw-questions-be-eligible-to-gain-rep/53727#53727) due to interference of people posting, not due to the merging.

Comment: @Grace: Alright.  Looks like those are pretty good confirmations of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Must have been fixed some time ago - I have taken a look at several recently converted to cw questions and all have a comment to the fact in the revision history.

I am putting a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) on this - but if you find other recent examples of the issue, let me know.

For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17552070/revisions - rev 7 [made Community Wiki by being edited by more than 5 different editors]