# Can Stack Overflow reputation be used on resumes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, jobs

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Has anyone ever used their gained reputation points to get a job or something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25453/has-anyone-ever-used-their-gained-reputation-points-to-get-a-job-or-something)
>   [At what point do you put your SO reputation in your resume?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume)

Can job seekers use reputation earned on Stack Overflow on their resumes? This could show employers that candidates they're considering hiring have good reputations in a community. It would also allow them to validate some of the answers posted by candidates, to gauge their depth of knowledge.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, but a lot of reputation on SO can mean you've been spending your work time on SO.

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409881/has-anyone-ever-used-their-gained-reputation-points-to-get-a-job-or-something-c

Comment: This is a question about Stack Overflow itself, so it belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25453/has-anyone-ever-used-their-gained-reputation-points-to-get-a-job-or-something

Answer (score 3):

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705660/using-stackoverflow-reputation/3705668#3705668) from SO got posted, but I'll repost here for ease:

This question's been asked on meta previously [(here)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume).  The general consensus is that unless you're a serious contributor and would be recognized by recruiters that have only slight to mild participation on SO, it seems like you're trying to pad your resume.  It differs by situation, though