# Citing StackOverflow on a boring (non-Careers 2.0) resume

Tags: discussion, jobs, stack-exchange

Lending from difficulties where I work and my current job search, I've been working a lot with StackOverflow lately. Answering people here has been tremendously useful for me, both for maintaining my sanity and for quietly reminding myself that what I does actually pretty darned useful. It's been lots of fun in an otherwise stressful time.

So, to begin on that point: thank you.

But I digress. Given my position and given feats that I frankly didn't think I was capable of here, I've been citing some of my achievements on SO in my LinkedIn profile. Just small things for now (eg, weekly ranking in the [unofficial leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues), moderator status), but I'm curious what the right criteria are for citation, which URIs I should be using, and whether this is a supported case *at all*, juxtaposed to [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

Given to only asking questions here when I can't find a good primary source, I searched Meta for comparable threads. What I found [wasn't especially encouraging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume), providing more of a historical note on perceptions of the reputation system back when things started than anything I can use for cogent, current advice.

If the advice is still "experience and skills come first," I can accept that (indeed, that's my current assumption). But, I'd like to think that with C2.O allowing prospective employers to rank and sort candidates by reputation and focus areas specifically, with a community at least one million strong, that SO now counts for a little more than a small bullet point to fill the space.

I *know* this is being worked on specifically in the context of the careers arm of the site, but I'm curious how you, the community, have made sense of this. I'm basically looking for a snapshot of how to handle this scenario currently, with some mind towards current and future plans that I may not be aware of.

And, as always, if a primary source, style guide, or amalgamation of references fits the bill, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed in my most recent job search a couple months ago that it's a growing trends among recruiters to ask for online profile where they can look you up. And specifically, I've been asked a couple times about my StackOverflow account (I didn't have one at that time sadly)

Now I would say that this is a nice addition to a resume, and once I've built my profile up, I won't be ashamed at all to put it on my resume.

Anyway even if you don't do so, you can be pretty sure that potential employers will google your name before any interview; I remember one time when I was interviewing with a startup, and I had to go find my interviewer at his desk, and he was just googling my name !

And regarding the "experience comes first", I'm not entirely ok with this. I've seen junior engineers with much more skills than some folks with 10+ years of experience. But due to the growing volume of applications, there is always a risk to miss some good profile, and I've read several articles saying that employers are relying more and more on online profiles like StackOverFlow than just plain old experience.

I hope that gives you some clues, this is indeed confusing times regarding the best way to apply for a job, I believe the ideal application has a mix of well-written resume, and some online presence.