# Does your SO account get a mention in your job applications?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I've always wondered whether those of you who have a good, solid reputation for helping others on stackoverflow mention this on your cv/in your job applications?

In my opinion, I think it should be deemed as recognisable to potential employers. Not as part of any sort of requirement by any means - but I think if you know your trade well enough to teach and help others, that should be valued. I certainly owe a lot to the members of SO for the amount I've learnt which has helped me in many situations in and out of employment - and I'd like to think that those who helped are recognised for it.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume

Comment: As one last point to your deleted question (will delete this comment asap), I don't know if its cashed but according to their [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1410501/ozkan) the user you think is downvoting you has only voted once today, and never downvoted

Answer (score 4):

I have an account on http://careers.stackoverflow.com, which automates this for me. The PDF export is my CV, and it contains:

> ### Projects & Interests
>
> Stack Overflow – https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297 -- May 2009
>   Current Written 1015 answers. Active in python, regex, string, django, xml and 29 other tags.

So, yes, I do mention it. My [online Careers 2.0 profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/zopatista) elaborates on that by including some of my posts.

Not that anyone has yet to remark on it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've placed it on my resume, and it's gained the attention of my interviewers for sure.  They remarked that they liked having that as a reference, and could see that I was genuine in my Java knowledge.

I do feel that people should put it on their resumes, as it gives employers a chance to see what you really know, and shows that you've contributed to the general community of programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

No, because I don't have a lot of points and it would be a shame.

Comment: Why would it be a shame? You're only here for 8 months and as long as your contribution were well formulated and not the pure noise kind I don't see any need for shame. It still shows that you're participating in a programming community, are genuinely interested in it and learning.

Comment: This is not an answer, as it ignores the premise: "those of you who have a good, solid reputation for helping others on stackoverflow"